# Is there any way to rest set/array to method parameters?

Tags: c++

Currently I have a function:

```cpp
void translate(std::string key, std::string& result, ...)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, result);
    vsnprintf (buffer, sizeof(buffer), (loadedTranslations.find(key) != loadedTranslations.end() ? loadedTranslations[key] : "unknown").c_str(), args);
    va_end(args);

    result = buffer;

}
```

I'm getting some data in AMX plugin and I need to pass them into this function. Is there are any way to do this? In JavaScript I can do something like `translate(a, b, ...rest)` and it will work. Is there some ways to implement same result in C++?  The problem is the data isn't one type: there can be integers, floats and strings. So using `std::forward` (if I correctly understood its use-case) not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
template <typename ... Args>
void translate(std::string key, std::string& result, Args&& ... args)
{
    // your code
}
```

and wherever you need to forward, for eg. to a function `foo`: `foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`

I'll suggest reading more about [variadic template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) and perfect forwarding.

Comment: But how should I call this function? For example, integer (1) and string ("hello") should be passed to args.

Comment: @ya.ymer `translate(myKey, myResult, 1, std::string("hello"))`